# Maximum likelihood estimation with unknown distribution

Tags: python, maximum-likelihood, statsmodels, bic

I want to fit a model to some data using structural time series modeling and Kalman filtering. The hyperparameters need to be tuned using maximum likelihood estimation.
I am using the Python package statsmodels that does this for me, but nowhere I need to put in which distribution I assume my model follows.

Does it automatically use a Gaussian distribution?

I am planning to select the right model using BIC. Should I check each one for normality first?
And if it's not, what would be a good next step to take?

Answer (score 0):

The `statespace` module in the python package only supports Gaussian distributed observation and state innovations (at least as of v0.14), so not only is it automatically used, but it cannot be changed.

What you should do depends on your model, but one easy first step would be to construct your state space model and then use the `[plot_diagnostics][1]` method to see if the residuals appear to be approximately Gaussian.